# Obtain primary name from list of aliases in Excel

Tags: excel, alias

I have a table of names with aliases divided into rows. 
[image]

I'm trying to obtain the clean name, in this example "Peter Parker". No matter if I search for "Operator PETER.PARKER" or "Operator Peter Parker", the function above only looks for the keyword in the first column, not in column 2 or 3.

I've searched for a native way in excel to deal with aliases, but either there is none, or I don't know where to look.

If possible I'd like to keep it simple (no vba).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an INDEX/MATCH formula, which is much more flexible then the other lookup functions in Excel. In this this case, your formula would be:

```
=INDEX(A1:A4;MAX(IFNA(MATCH(B6;B1:B4;0);0);IFNA(MATCH(B6;C1:C4;0);0)))
```

Both `MATCH` functions will find the row number for your lookup value in `B6` in both column `B` and `C`.
Be aware, if your lookup value in `B6` gives a match in both column `B` and `C`, the MAX function will pick the match with the highest row number.
The `INDEX` function the looks up the corresponding name in column `A`.

Comment: Awesome, that works great! I see the issue with the lookup value being at B6. I'll probably only use the function on a hidden tab, so the location of the lookup value wont matter where it is. Thank you!

Comment: @Dutchman thank you for the feedback. It seems I made little mistake. Your lookup value is in B6 and I wrote the formula with the lookup value being in C6. I have now fixed it.

Comment: no problem, I caught that one too, but figured that one out :) . I do have another question though. The function will be used in a list of random names, so there is a chance the lookup value does not appear in the search range. How can I display the original B6 value if the return of the INDEX function results in #VALUE! ? I tried IFNA, but perhaps I'm applying it wrong

Comment: You can put it into an `IFERROR` function and specify cell B6 (I guess you mean B6, right?) as the cell to display on error. It would look something like: `=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:A4;MAX(IFNA(MATCH(B6;B1:B4;0);0);IFNA(MATCH(B6;C1:C4;0);0)));B6)`.

Comment: You just beat me to it, I should've googled before asking. ```IFERROR``` is indeed the addition I needed to get it working properly. Thanks again!